# How is the caret emulated in Etherpad?

Tags: javascript, html, etherpad

How is the blinking caret emulated in Etherpad? (See a live version at ietherpad.com)
The way I would do it, is to create a div and position it absolutely where the caret should be. Then, display and remove it in regular intervals. However they seem to do it differently.

The text of a row is in

```
<div id="magicdomid2" class="">...</div>
```

I can't see anything changing around the div. How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't emulated. In modern browsers, Etherpad creates an `iframe` containing a document with the tag:

```
<body contenteditable="true">
```

Which tells the browser to allow editing of the contained HTML document. The carat is one of the effects of including that attribute.